# How to restrict some users to commit in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnlook

I want to restrict certain users to commit a particular dirrectory, so that they just have Read only access. How can we do that. I have a pre commit hook which is defined as below :

```
   REPOS="$1"
   TXN="$2"

   # Make sure that the log message contains some text.
   SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
   $SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
   grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1

   commit-access-control.pl "$REPOS" "$TXN" commit-access-control.cfg || exit 1

   # All checks passed, so allow the commit.
   exit 0
```

Can we include the check to restrict the users in this hookup file if so how can we do that precisely.
Or there are 'commit-access-control.pl' and 'commit-access-control.cfg' mentioned in this hookuup. Do we need to change this file to include the user which needs to be restricted ? I was trying to find the files but not able to find them. can somebody let me know the exact location where I can find these files ?

Sorry for all the naive questions but I am new to SVN.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [path-based authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) to implement user restrictions (permissions) in your Subversion repositories.

Comment: Hi I am now trying to use path-based -authorization. I have a working repository as follows:  "C:/SVNRepository/Test_Parent_folder/Test_child/ ", that I need to restrict. Can you please suggest how should I frame "[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142]"  as mentioned in the document for my repository ? I am trying to write "C:/SVNRepositorywc/TEST_AG/TEST_AG_child" in the authz file, but it doesn't seem to be picked up. I have also added 'authz-db = authz' to the svnserve.conf. but I believe my repository path is not correct. Can you please suggest

Comment: @Abha  You need to ask a different question when you have a new question and provide full server config, logs and authz files examples.